# Submit a form with ajax when there is more than one on a page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering how to submit a form on a page with AJAX (just one form) when there are more than 4 forms on that same page.

What I have so far, that isn't working:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("findPatientRecords").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var username = $("username").val();
      var searchPatientRecords = $("searchPatientRecords").val();
      $(".formMessage").load("inc/findPatientRecords.php", {
        username: username,
        searchPatientRecords: searchPatientRecords
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the form is:

```
<form method="post" name="findPatientRecords" id="findPatientRecords" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;" name="searchPatientRecords">Search for user</button>
          <p id="formMessage"></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: How? With writing some javascript code.

Comment: Does it look like I know how? Or am I asking?!

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you don't know how to submit a form with javascript - open google and search. Or even search here.

Comment: The amount of forms on a page shouldn't be a problem. Just give the submit buttons unique id's to trigger different ajax functions.

Comment: html: <form id="id here">form here</form> and js: document.getElementById("id here").submit() or $("#id here").submit(); i don't think that's so hard

Answer (score 0):

use name attribute in form element

```
<form name="form1">
```

Comment: Why? How would this help?

Comment: The name attribute specifies the name of a form.The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer my help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery finds elements similar to CSS selectors. To find an element with an `id` attribute of `foo`, you would need to do `#foo`. If you omit the `#` sign, it will instead try to find a `<foo>` element. This is why your jQuery selectors are not matching anything.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#findPatientRecords").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var searchPatientRecords = $("#searchPatientRecords").val();
      $(".formMessage").load("inc/findPatientRecords.php", {
        username: username,
        searchPatientRecords: searchPatientRecords
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```